# One word for "when a game suits some one very much"

Tags: single-word-requests

One word when we want to say somebody that the games suits them.

For example, "Given his natural athletic ability and quick responses, that game really _____.

Comment: Given that you will need to indicate "him" with whatever word you choose, *suited* seems exactly right. "The game really suited him." You could even omit *him* at a pinch: "The game really suited," or "The game was really suited." **Why** do you think *suited* won't work here?

Comment: allowing more thav a word may be helpful to answering this question

Answer (score 1):

"Given his natural athletic ability and quick responses, that game could not be more **apt**.’

Definition of **apt** in English: [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/apt)

adjective

> 1 Appropriate or suitable in the circumstances.
>
> ‘the theme could not be more apt’